# RGB Image to Greyscale

Tags: python, image-processing

for one of my classes, were converting a colored image to greyscale using Python without using a library. I have everything set up so far except for the conversion which I cant figure out and haven't found anything to solve this.

Here is my code:

```
from graphics import *

def main():

    print("This program will take a colored image \nand make make a new image in 
    greyscale")

    filename = input("What is the name of your image: ")
    savefile = input("What would you like the file saved as: ")

    win = GraphWin("Project 3", 640, 640)
    win.setCoords(0, 0, 640, 640)
    Text(Point(320, 320), "Click to begin!").draw(win)
    win.getMouse()
    picture = Image(Point(320, 320), filename)
    picture.draw(win)

    width = 640
    height = 640

    for i in range(width):
        for j in range(height):
```

Comment: You need to finish the code, my friend…

Comment: Here is an article on some common methods... 
https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/08/24/algorithms-convert-color-grayscale/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the body of your loop:

```
colors = picture.getPixel(i, j)
average = sum(colors) / 3.0
picture.setPixel(i, j, [average, average, average])
```